# PHP while (list($key, ) = each($array)) vs. while (list($key) = each($array))

Tags: php

I have been going through the entire documentation and stackoverflow Q&A and couldn't find any answer for this.
In php, are these two `while` the exact same or are there differences between them. And if so, which?

```
while (list($key, ) = each($array))
```

and

```
while (list($key) = each($array))
```

I know I can convert the first to

```
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key)
```

But can I do the same conversion to `while (list($key) = each($array))`?

Comment: The `each()` function is [deprecated](http://php.net/each) and will be removed in a future PHP version.

Comment: Having said that, a quick [test script](https://3v4l.org/NnWGF) seems to indicate that the second while-loop does exactly the same thing as the first, so you could use the same solution.

Comment: Thanks, @rickdenhaan. The reason I am asking is exactly because `each` is deprecated and I am adapting the script to php 7.2, and thus don't want to make any mistakes while adapting the code to use `foreach`.

Comment: @rickdenhaan, off-topic, but isn't it odd that your script take 14ms on php 5.6.30 and 23ms (almost double time) on php 7.2.7?

Comment: Not particularly. The array in that test script only contains 5 items, with that small a sample the script's runtime is heavily influenced by other system resource usage. I just tried running the same script with an array that has 100.000 items in it, that took 313 ms on PHP 5.6 and 110 ms on PHP 7.2.

Comment: Incredible! Thank you @rickdenhaan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @rickdenhaan for his test script that shows they are identical, I wanted to point out that there is 1 more way to convert `while (list($key, ) = each($array))`:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
```

Examples:
https://3v4l.org/NV8MD